# Setting new values in `org-refile-target` not working

Tags: customize, setq, persistence

I'm trying to add a new file `foo.org` and delete an old `bar.org` from the `org-refile-target` variable. So doing

```
(setq org-refile-targets   (quote (("~/foo.org" :maxlevel . 2))
```

should work by replacing the former

```
(setq org-refile-targets   (quote (("~/bar.org" :maxlevel . 2))
```

However, if I run the new code (i.e., the first line above), then the fix only works in the current session. Upon re-start changes are lost.

And even in the current session, if I do `C-h v org-refile-target` I see the changes under the `Value` heading. But the old settings are under the headings `saved-value` and `theme-value`. How come?

By the way, previously I was using

```
(custom-set-variables
      '(org-refile-targets '(("~/foo.org" :maxlevel . 2)
```

with the same result. Plus I don't have a `custom` file that loads on Emacs's startup.

I've tried `org-refile-cache-clear` to no avail... so where on earth are the old settings stored and how can I override them?? Is `setq-default` the answer? (just tested and it is not the answer)

Comment: I don't know about the current session problem, but about the restarting problem: you are probably setting it in your init file (`$HOME/.emacs` or `$HOME/.emacs.d/init.el`).

Comment: Hi Nick, sorry, I forgot to mention all of my editings are in `init.el`, hence my surprise. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Why are the parentheses not matching?

Answer (score -1):

Use `M-x customize-option` to change the value to whatever you want - and save it. *Customize **persists** your settings; `setq` does not.*

If you don't use a separate `custom-file` (I recommend you do use one), which you then load from your init file, then Customize saves your settings in your init file.

If you don't want to use the Customize UI then you can use function `customize-set-variable` or `custom-set-variables`, instead. They don't persist the settings they make, but you can use them in your init file to set things when it's loaded. (You can also use `customize-save-variable` or `custom-save-variables`.)

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your reply. I don't like using any point-and-click solution as in `M-x customize-option`. `setq` or `setq-default` on your `init.el` *should* be loaded and applied on startup. However, sometimes one messes up the powers of `setq` by having a `custom-file`, which is why I've deleted mine. The question is, How come my settings are not affected *completely* by my variable definition in my `init.el`?

Comment: `setq` and `setq-default` do what you expect in your init file, assuming your init file gets loaded (*does it?*). Put a call to `message` after your `setq` in your init file, to see if it took effect properly. It's also possible that something else done after you set it overrides that setting. This `message` call will tell you about that too. (`setq-default` is only needed if the variable is sometimes or always buffer-local.)

Comment: I've just checked and the messages I've written before and after my   `setq org-refile-targets` are printed, so the code is run... The only plausible thing is that there is something reverting my changes but I don't find anything obvious... my main suspect was the `custom` file but I don't have one... uhhhhhmmmm

Comment: Would someone like to explain the downvote?